# How to insert a list into another list?

Tags: list, clojure

If I have this list:

```
(ham chicken)
```

And this list:

```
(bread bread)
```

How can I make a 'sandwich' that looks like this:

```
(bread (ham chicken) bread)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With deconstructing:

```
((fn [[a b] c] (list a c b))  '(bread bread) '(ham chicken))
=> (bread (ham chicken) bread)
```

Comment: almost at same time! :)

Comment: IMO, it's more readable to do this kind of ad-hoc destructuring in a let rather than an anonymous function. For example, `(let [[a b] '(bread bread), c '(ham chicken)] (list a c b))`

Comment: Yes @Chuck i agree with you that your code style is more readable, but my code is the result of 4clojure problems, overall the influence of bmaddy user code http://www.4clojure.com/user/bmaddy, which is almost a clojure haiku poet  :)

Comment: The 4clojure thing is great - I just discovered it myself the other day - great for trying to get fluent in this weird and wonderful language !

Answer (score 0):

OK - got something that works....

```
(def wrapper '(bread bread))
(def filling '(ham chicken)) 
(list (first wrapper) filling (last wrapper) )
```